# Perform Selection Sort On 2D Char Array

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I currently have a 2D char array size: [5][256].

The array can hold either numbers or letters.
I have been tasked with using the Selection Sort to sort the strings into ascending order.

My idea is to convert each row into ASCII and then sort the values in ascending order then convert back to chars.

Ive implemented a 2D Array Selection sort for another task, however, it doesnt work here as i coded it to work with 2 columns not 256 like here (not sure how to change it).

What i need help with is how do i use the ASCII value for each row and use it in a selection sort.

Been trying to figure this out for hours now, driving me mental.

Any help is appreciated.

Im not necessarily looking for someone to code everything for me, more of a kick in the right direction. Im new to C and not aware of every function C can do.

Here is my current code in full:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
char    arc5Strings[5][256];
int nCount, nCount2, nCount3, nCount4, nCount5, nCount6, nCount7;


int fMinVal[1][2] = {1,1};
int nMinValPosition;
int nMoves;
int nRow;
int fTemp[1][2] = {1,1};
int fTemp2[1][2] = {1,1};

//input the values

for(nCount=0; nCount < 5; nCount++)
{
    printf("Please input string %d/5: ", nCount + 1);
    fgets(arc5Strings[nCount], 256, stdin);

}

printf("\n\n");

//print entire array
for(nCount3 = 0; nCount3 < 5; nCount3++)
{
    for(nCount4 = 0; arc5Strings[nCount3][nCount4] != '\0'; nCount4++)
    {
        printf("%d ", arc5Strings[nCount3][nCount4]);

        //ASCII values outputted in a line instead of in array format when using %c
    }

}



return 0;
}
```

Old 2D Array selection sort i devised - extracted from code:

```
//-----------------------------------       
//set up the switch       

for(nCount5 = 0; nCount5 < 5; nCount5++)
{
    fMinVal[0][0] = arc5Strings[nCount5][0]; //min value is row 0 col 1
    nMinValPosition = nCount5;

    for(nCount6 = nCount5 + 1; nCount6 < 5; nCount6++)
    {
        if(arc5Strings[nCount6][1] < fMinVal[0][0])
        {
            fMinVal[0][0] = arc5Strings[nCount6][0];

            nMinValPosition = nCount6; 
        } 
        /* Perform the switch - actually switch the values */
        if(fMinVal[0][0] < arc5Strings[nCount5][0])
        {
            fTemp[0][1] = arc5Strings[nCount5][1];
            fTemp2[0][0] = arc5Strings[nCount5][0];

            arc5Strings[nCount5][1] = arc5Strings[nMinValPosition][1];
            arc5Strings[nCount5][0] = arc5Strings[nMinValPosition][0];
            arc5Strings[nMinValPosition][1] = fTemp[0][1];
            arc5Strings[nMinValPosition][0] = fTemp2[0][0];


            nMoves++;
        }
    }
}


//------------------------------   
    printf("\n\n");

        printf("The sorted list, in ascending order, using selection sort, is:\n\n");
    for(nCount3 = 0; nCount3 < 5; nCount3++)
    {
        for(nCount4 = 0; arc5Strings[nCount3][nCount4] != '\0'; nCount4++)
        {
            printf("%c", arc5Strings[nCount3][nCount4]);
        }

    }

    printf("\n %d moves were made to sort this list\n", nMoves);
```

EDIT - RESULTS OF GEORGE'S ANSWER:

```
Input1 = 90
Input2 = 70
Input3 = abc
Input4 = 500
Input5 = 200

Sorted Array Results:
200
90
70
abc
500
```

Comment: What do you mean sort the strings?

Comment: Sort the strings into ascending order based on their ASCII values

Comment: Sorting by length, first letter value etc. By what?

Comment: Ah sorry, should make myself clear.

If "123" has ASCII values of "49 50 51" and "012" is "48 49 50". 

123 = 495051 - 012 = 484950. Then 012 would come first as it has a lower value.

Comment: Are you adding individual ASCII nalues?

Comment: My logic is that if i use the ASCII values to sort them then i can convert them back again after to output them in ascending order. I started C about a month or so ago so i may be going about this completely the wrong way. If you can think of a better way then i would love some advice mate

Comment: I mean, are you adding 49+50+51 and 48+49+50 to find the larger?

Comment: No, i basically want to concat 49,50 and 51 to get "495051" and compare it to the concat value of 012 which is "484950"

Comment: it seems strcmp can do what you want..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. I would implement this as follows:

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
 indexOfCurrentSmallest = i;
 for(j=i;j<5;j++)
 {
  for(k=0;k<255;k++)
  {
    if(arc5Strings[j][k] < arc5Strings[indexOfCurrentSmallest][k])
    {
      //we found a new possible smallest
      indexOfCurrentSmallest = j;
      break;
    }
    else if(arc5Strings[j][k] > arc5Strings[indexOfCurrentSmallest][k])
    {
        //no point in searching further, the one we are looking at is already larger than the one we found.
        break;
    }
  }

 }
 //here, we have found the actual smallest, let's do a swap
 for(q=0;q<255;q++)
 {
  temp = arc5Strings[i][q];
  arc5Strings[i][q] = arc5Strings[indexOfCurrentSmallest][q];
  arc5Strings[indexOfCurrentSmallest][q] = temp;
 }
}
```

I haven't tested this code, but it should be roughly what you're looking for. Basically, it compares ASCII values starting at the left, until it finds a difference, and stores the index for later swapping after comparing all 5 strings.

**EDIT** I've now tested the code above, and it works now.

Comment: Hi George, thanks for your answer. I have implemented this. I feel like im extremely close to the right answer but the sorted array is slightly off. I have added in the results to the OP - Im going to have a bit more of an indepth look at this and see if i can figure it out

Comment: Hey Dr. Pepper. I've tested the code now and fixed it (and made it a bit more efficient). I used your list and it sorted it correctly:

1.200
2.500
3.70
4.90
5.abc

Comment: Thanks for that George, its much appreciated. Can stop banging my head now! I was glad to know i was on the right lines in the first place! :)

Answer (score 0):

First find each string length

```
int length[5];
for(i = 0, i < 5, i++){
    length[i] = strlen(arc5Strings[i]);
}
```

Sort the lengths. Those with the same, compare the value of the first letter.
Thats it.

valter